# Google People API not returning all phone number sources

Tags: google-people-api

I'm trying to use the Google People API to get the authenticated user's phone number that is associated with their Google account by using the `people.get` method and the resource name of `person/me`.

I tried this out on both a web application using the scopes `profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read`, as well as with the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get). In both cases, I only see the authenticated user's phone number if it happens to be listed in their Google+ profile account.

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.SourceType), a user's Google account is one of the sources of data that the Google People API retrieves from. Can the API include account phone numbers as part of the information returned for `person/me`?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are running into https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78151501.